Clients to send text messages through a USB Dongle on Windows?
I almost always utilize GNU/Linux. However, recently I have to utilize Windows for a little while. As such, I am having some difficulty finding some functionalities.
On GNU/Linux, you can utilize a variety of tools to send text messages if you have access to a USB LTE Modem / Cellular Dongle (Chatty, ModemManager, and I think even Pidgin). But, alas, I cannot find any similar apps on Windows.
Does Windows support sending/receiving text messages? How can I receive text messages on my Windows laptop?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Windows has no support for sending SMS, but if you have a notebook with built-in GSM modem or an USB GSM modem that allows to send AT commands you can use the AT command AT+CMGS to send SMS (which is most likely the way also used on Linux).

Is there a reason your not using a simpler method like google chat?  It is definitely cross platform as you can just launch firefox or etc and login to google.

@cybernard It is because I also appreciate the usage of Cellular Data and want to utilize the same phone as the one I used to utilize within my phone.
